# How to set a layout over half sized screen height layout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

The XML layout is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_bg">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login Card"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="28dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And it turns out that the second linear layout will be placed below to the first layout.I want the first layout size to be half of the screen and the second layout will be placed the bottom of the first layout not below to the first layout.

I am trying Ui like this

[image]

If anyone knows how do I solve this problem.please comment below :)

Comment: it easy to do with `ConstraintLayout` https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_rect"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="name"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="password"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign in "
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[You can see here output image that above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUBba.png)

Answer (score 1):

use constraint layout for these types of layout. Drag and drop from palette and fix in preview. check sample

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="SignIn"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="293dp"
    android:layout_height="238dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.066">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Frame layout. Inside use a linear layout for the colors with only 2 views for the background. Then add below the linear layout with all the ui components.